# re-initialize the framebuffer when program crashes

Tags: nvidia, framebuffer

I'm using SDL to display images on a monitor, without X installed.

When my program ends successfully, the monitor goes back to the login prompt (as expected). But when my program crashes, the last image stays frozen on the monitor (even if I launch the program again, the last image of the previous execution stays stuck on the monitor).

How could I kill the display in order to "use" it again ? The only solution that I found is to reboot the computer but I need to avoid that because other processes run on the computer and cannot be interrupted.

Comment: Most of the time when the GPU gets wedged the only way out is a reboot.