# Linux framebuffer not reverting to text console when netsurf crashes

Tags: linux-kernel, framebuffer

On an older computer running Linux (using vesafb, musl libc, busybox), [Netsurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/) will occasionally segfault in low memory situations. When it does so, the last image stays visible on the display, and typing seems to do nothing, including trying to switch VT using `Ctrl-Alt-Fx`. I'd like to know why it does this, and how to fix it.

I can happily SSH into the machine and shut it down, and there doesn't seem to be anything in dmesg. This doesn't happen on a machine with an intel GPU, running Arch (systemd). The behavior is similar to that described at [re-initialize the framebuffer when program crashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119285/re-initialize-the-framebuffer-when-program-crashes), and is also using SDL.

According to https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/how-vt-switching-works/, the kernel should be handling VT switching, so this behavior seems quite surprising to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by SDL setting the terminal mode to `KD_GRAPHICS` and input to `K_MEDIUMRAW`. `KD_GRAPHICS` causes the terminal to stop drawing to the display, while `K_MEDIUMRAW` causes the input to be passed as keycodes (not characters). By resetting both values to `KD_TEXT` and `K_XLATE` or `K_UNICODE`, the terminal can be (at least partially) restored.

I wrote (based on some existing code) a small program for restoring the console, which seems to work well: https://github.com/hobbitalastair/termfix

See also [Best practice for hiding virtual console while rendering video to framebuffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173712/best-practice-for-hiding-virtual-console-while-rendering-video-to-framebuffer?rq=1) and http://lct.sourceforge.net/lct/x60.html.

Comment: great fix `termfix` <3